# Búsqueda de datos entre 2 fechas Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-mvc, jpql

yo rabiando un poco. Miren tengo 2 fechas tomadas desde un calendario en html. El tema es que las fechas me las toma bien, pero a la hora de consultar a la bd las tengo que formatear a date, las formateo y me da el tipo completo de fecha, cuando la paso a buscar  a la bd obtengo cero resultado. Pero cuando le paso una fecha manual hecha por mi me da resultados de búsqueda . El tema es que no se que hago mal al formatear o pasar las fechas en la búsqueda. Adjunto código.

**FORMULARIO DONDE PASO LAS FECHAS**

```
            <form th:action="@{/fecha}" method="get" >
                <div>
                <label>Desde</label>
                 <input type="date" th:name="desde"   />
                 <label>Hasta</label>
                 <input type="date" th:name="hasta"  />
                 </div>

                 <button type="submit">Buscar</button>
                 </form>
```

Funciona bien ya que con un syso me las muestra por pantalla correctamente y en el servicio que hago la lógica las muestra que las recibe correctamente tamb !

**ADJUNTO COD CONTROLADOR**

```
@RequestMapping("/fecha")
@ResponseBody//Usos response para ver resultado de consultas rapido
public List<String> mostrar(@RequestParam(value = "desde" , defaultValue = "01/01/1800")String desde,
        @RequestParam (value ="hasta")String hasta, ModelAndView mp
        ) throws ParseException {
    //Paso fechas a servicio
    mp.addObject("hola", movimientoServicio.buscarFecha(desde, hasta));
    System.out.println(desde+"    "+hasta);
    return movimientoServicio.buscarFecha(desde, hasta);

}
```

**ADJUNTO COD SERVICIO**

```
    public List<String> buscarFecha(String desde, String hasta) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date desdee = formater.parse(desde);
    Date hastaa = formater.parse(hasta);

        System.out.println("desde = "+desdee+" hastaa = "+hastaa);
    List<String> vs =  ventasRepository.findByAllData(desdee,hastaa);   
    return vs;  

}
```

**CONSULTA EN REPO**

```
    @Query("SELECT Distinct  d.descripcion FROM Venta v INNER JOIN v.detallevtas d WHERE v.idVenta = d.idVenta AND d.fecha BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2 ")

public List<String> findByAllData(Date des,Date has);
```

Aca en BETWEEN cuando meto fechas manuales ponele tal que así '2018-09-01' AND '2019-09-01' Me toma la búsqueda de diez! El tema es con parámetros. 
Bueno eso es todo agradezco la ayuda enormemente si ven un ERROR seguiré intentando.

Comment: ¿Tus variables casteadas en formato `Date` tienen el formato requerido para la query?, ¿Por qué no mejor las pasas directo en `String` a tu repositorio solo cambia tu método a `findByAllData(String des, String has)`, algo más que podrías intentar es usar el método `Between` de JPA [ https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.0.0.M1/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation ]

Comment: No paso String porque no me lo recibe ya que en mi BD esta con date la fecha y da error.  Igual ya lo resolví, era que no estaba pasando bien los parámetros se pasan así mira.
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT v FROM Venta v JOIN v.detallevtas d WHERE d.fecha BETWEEN :desde AND :hasta")

------------->
 Page<Venta> findByAllData(@Param("desde") Object object, @Param("hasta") Object object2, Pageable page);
La query es distinta a la que deje el día del error !

Answer (score 1):

Intentaste recibir las fechas como LocalDate y no como String? 
quedaria asi:

```
@RequestMapping("/fecha")
@ResponseBody
public List<String> mostrar(
       @RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) LocalDate 
       desde,
        @RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) LocalDate 
       hasta, ModelAndView mp
        ) throws ParseException {
    mp.addObject("hola", movimientoServicio.buscarFecha(desde, hasta));
    System.out.println(desde+"    "+hasta);
    return movimientoServicio.buscarFecha(desde, hasta);

}
```

1. Tu servicio deberia recibir un LocalDate.
2. Si el nombre del parametro es el mismo del que le estan pasando no es necesario (value = "desde")
3. Al raro que veo es que estas ejecutando el servio 2 veces y tranquilamente podria ejecutarlo 1 sola vez, agregarlo a la lista de mp y devolverlo.
4. Si el repository implementa de JpaRepository no es necesario hacer
   el @query, podes usar el metodo BETWEEN de JPA:

```
   public List<String> findByAllDataBetween(Date des,Date has);
```

Espero te sirva, Saludos!

Comment: Ya lo había solucionado pero gracias por aportar al conocimiento, slaudos !